# Sails JS - Waterline ORM - Query Date only, not Time

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Looking to query against the **date only** anyone encountered this?

Sample code:

```
    ////MODEL
    module.exports = {
      attributes: {
        date: {
            type: 'date',
            required: true
        }    
      }
    };

    ////CONTROLLER
    var today = moment().toISOString();

    var queryObj = { date: today };
    var newDay = { date: today };

    Day.findOrCreate(queryObj, newDay).exec(function(err, day) {            
        console.log(day)
    });
```

Obviously this creates a new record on each refresh, as the iso string will change with each passing second.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a comment that `type:'date'` is being deprecated in Sails v1.x.  I think the advised method is to `type:'string', columnType:'date'` (or timestamp)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of querying for a single date, you can query for a date *range* that includes all of today.  First, you'll need to actually create values for that range--I whipped this up using Moment, but there's probably a better way:

```
var begin = moment(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")).toISOString();
var end = moment(moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")).add(1, 'days').toISOString();
```

Then you can use query operators to search the range:

```
var queryObj = {date: {'>=': begin, '<': end}};
Day.findOrCreate(queryObj, newDay).exec(function(err, day) {            
    console.log(day)
});
```

As always, be mindful of time zone issues!

Comment: DUHH how did I miss that! #linearthinking -- thanks friend.